# python regex(VALIDATING ROMAN NUMBERS)

Tags: python

```
import re

print( True if (re.search(r"^M{0,4}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})$",input())) else False)
```

in the following code that which check if a given roman numerical is valid or not why is a different answer printed when ^ and $ are not included in the print statement, etc.,. theoretically the ^ and $ are just to show the matching pattern in the beginning and end.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: Because `re.search()` and `re.match()` are not the same.

`re.search()` searches for a match to the given pattern in the entire input, while `re.match()` requires the pattern to match at the beginning of the input.
Independent of that, you can force the pattern to match only at the beginning/end of the input with ^/$. See [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#search-vs-match) for a detailed explanation.

In your case `re.search(your_pattern_without_^)` would match `"QQQQXII"` because nothing enforces a match over the entire input. On the other hand `re.search(your_pattern_with_^)` or `re.match(your_pattern_without_^)` would not match `"QQQQXII"` because either the pattern or `re.match()` requires a match at the start of the input.